# why my momentjs always display the minute at 03?

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

so I use momentjs in my application, this is the code:

```
moment.lang('id');
moment(value).format('DD-MMMM-YYYY HH:MM');
```

but the result is strange, the day, month, year and hour is right but the minute always displaying at 03, I dont know why, can somebody explain it and how do I make it right? thanks

Comment: cause MM is the month? mm is the minutes.

Comment: @d--b yeah, thats the answer, oh my God, I am such a fool. Thanks a lot

Comment: @d--b I cant accept an answer before 10 minutes, wait for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
moment.lang('id');
moment(value).format('DD-MMMM-YYYY hh:mm');
```

Comment: Probably should be `HH:mm`, or `hh:mm a`